# Accesing remote server in linux using bash script

Tags: bash

```
n=rijotests143.revsw.net
echo $n
me=$(echo $n | sed 's/"/ /g')
echo $me
u=$(echo $me | sed 's/\./\_/g')
echo $u

ssh -i m_bp.pem ubuntu@95.68.74.51 'bash -s' < domain_delbp.sh
```

I am getting accessed to the remote server and passing values in domain_delbp.sh file. In this i need to pass a value of $u in domain_delbp.sh and need to execute the command

```
cat /opt/rijo/var/$u.json
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can simply parse the value to the script and in the script you can access that value as `$1` variable.

```
n=rijotests143.revsw.net 
echo $n me=$(echo $n | sed 's/"/ /g')
echo $me u=$(echo $me | sed 's/./_/g')
echo $u 
ssh -i m_bp.pem ubuntu@95.68.74.51 'bash -s' < domain_delbp.sh $u
```